# How to keep postgres flexible server and aks on the same vnet?

Tags: postgresql, azure-networking, aks

I have created aks cluster with azure network type selected.

Terraform files for [reference](https://github.com/thunderbirds-2021/terraform_testing/tree/main/azure_aks_cluster_with_azure_storage)

My VNet used with aks.

[image: vnet of aks]

But this vnet is not available in the dropdown of azure postgres flexible server creation.

[image: vnet not showing from above screen]

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: yeah got it, by creating a separate subnet without any resources in it

Comment: @romaneso how did you end up handling connectivity between the cluster and postgres?  Checked the github link don't see anything around Postgres, trying to figure out the best way of connecting flexible server with aks cluster